# During View data not getting captured in the Controller in ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC. I am new to ASP.Net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to implement Update/Edit functionality in ASP.Net Core using Razor.  Below is the view page.

After clicking Submit button the view page is POSTed to the "GetCustomerForEdit" method of the controller as mentioned below in the code.  But unfortunately the edited data from the view is not transferred to the controller method "GetCustomerForEdit", parameter "EditCustomer" of type "GetAllCustDetails".

Since i am new to ASP.net Core is there something i am missing or not doing right in the View or Controller?

VIEW CODE:

```
<form asp-action="GetCustomerForEdit">
    <div>
        <table class="tables1">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Custs)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:300px;" colspan="2">Update Customers 
                        Details</th>
                </tr>

                <tr style="visibility:hidden">
                  <td><input asp-for="@item.CustomerId" type="hidden" />/td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.FirstName" autofocus 
                        class="textbox1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.LastName" class="textbox1" /> 
                                                                      </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sex</td>
                    <td><select asp-for="@item.Sex" class="textbox1" asp- 
     items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.listofitems, "Sex", "Sex"))"></select>                           
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Age" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 177px">Address1</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Address1" class="textbox1" 
                                                     type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address2</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Address2" class="textbox1" 
                                                     type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.State" class="textbox1" 
                                                    type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.City" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pin</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Pin" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Phone" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Mobile" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@item.Email" class="textbox1" 
                                                   type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            }

            <tr class="trfooter">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
                    <input type="reset" class="submit" value="Reset" />
                    <input type="button" class="submit" value="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        @if (TempData["RecordSave"] != null)
        {
            <p>@TempData["RecordSave"]</p>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

MODEL CODE:

```
public class GetAllCustDetails
{
public int CustomerId { get; set; }

public string FirstName { get; set; }

public string LastName { get; set; }

public List<Customer> Custs;
}
```

Where Customer model:

```
public class Customer
{
public int CustomerId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter First Name!")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter Last Name!")]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter Sex!")]
public string Sex { get; set; }

[Range(0,99)]
[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter valid Age!")]
public int Age { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter valid Adddress!")]
public string Address1 { get; set; }

public string Address2 { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter State!")]
public string State { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter valid State!")]
public string City { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter valid Pin!")]
public int Pin { set; get; }

public long Phone { set; get; }

public long  Mobile { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="  Please enter valid Email!")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required field!")]
public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

CONTROLLER CODE: [HttpGet is working fine]

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCustomerForEdit(Int16? Id)
{
GetAllCustDetails getCustForEdit;
clsCustomerDAL getCust;

getCust = new clsCustomerDAL();
getCustForEdit = getCust.GetCustomerForUpdate(Id);
SexDropDown();// this is dropdown getting populated from DB

return View(getCustForEdit);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetCustomerForEdit([Bind] GetAllCustDetails 
       EditCustomer)
{
bool retVal = false;
int CustId = 0;
string Fname;
string Lname;
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    clsCustomerDAL updateCust = new clsCustomerDAL();                

    retVal = updateCust.DALEditCustomer(EditCustomer);

    if(retVal == true)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    return View("getCustomerDetails");
}
return View("IndexPage");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to pass a List of `Customer` from View to controller, for model binding, you could specify `name` property for each input.

Edit view:

```
@model GetAllCustDetails
    <form asp-action="GetCustomerForEdit">           
        <div>
            <table class="tables1">

                @{int i = 0;}

                @foreach (var item in Model.Custs)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:300px;" colspan="2">
                            Update Customers
                            Details
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="visibility:hidden">
                        <td><input asp-for="@item.CustomerId" type="hidden" name="Custs[@i].CustomerId" />/td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@item.FirstName" name="Custs[@i].FirstName"  autofocus class="textbox1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    //other <tr> properties

                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@item.Email" name="Custs[@i].Email" class="textbox1" type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    i++;
                }

                <tr class="trfooter">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        <input type="reset" class="submit" value="Reset" />
                        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            @if (TempData["RecordSave"] != null)
            {
                <p>@TempData["RecordSave"]</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetCustomerForEdit([Bind] GetAllCustDetails EditCustomer)
```

Comment: Hi Xing Zou. Thanks for your valuable suggestion i tried to implement your suggestion but the view returns empty model to the controller method "[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetCustomerForEdit([Bind] GetAllCustDetails 
       EditCustomer)".

Comment: It is strange.Do you try to add {get;set;} to let the `GetAllCustDetails` model have a field `public List<Customer> Custs { get; set; }`.The `name` property is for model-bonding, try to remove EditCustomer. in it like `name="Custs[@i].FirstName"`

Comment: Extremely Sorry my bad.  Your are right somehow i missed the step "List<Customer> Custs { get; set; }" i.e. did not defined {get; set;}.  Now it's working like charm. Xing Zou i appreciate your help thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.You could mark the reply as answer if you have resolved your problem.